# Error: In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to combine 3 tables, each on a separate Google Sheet, and each table has the same 3 columns and has its header in row 1. Other than the actual data, the tables are all exactly the same. But I am getting the error:

**'In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows'**

I have browsed other posts with this same error and they are all about situations where the tables did not have the same number of columns. But my tables DO HAVE the same number of columns:

Here is my formula:

```
=query({IMPORTRANGE("1673t-7ZEzpZenbeK_HjCYyo824th4YE8Vt9YAn1J0nU","Sheet1!A1:C4");IMPORTRANGE("1J5VRivxfxToObBikLAKfNDNX4ibxvIWphcjohw0B8Ms","Sheet1!A2:C4");IMPORTRANGE("1DRSAyjDN7v6UNjFiBtMvrfzIewV8_iE-GjrGkNBPwIU","Sheet1!A2:C4")},"Select Col1, Col2, Col3",1)
```

Since I want headers to appear in my query result, I am including row 1 from the first sheet. I therefore reference range A1:C4 for that table but then only reference range A2:C4 for the next 2 tables.

Any input on why I am getting this error? Thanks

Comment: try first separately and give authorization fir each spreadsheet, may be the error comes from a lack of coupling between spreadsheets

Comment: Thanks Mike, that was the problem. Pulling each table into my google sheet separately as a preliminary step allows google sheets to first show an REF error but then that REF error message gives me to an 'allow access' button'. Hopefully this will help others in the future. For some reason I can't mark your answer as 'accepted'. Maybe because it is my first post?

Comment: no, because it is a comment, not an answer I have added, now you will be able to accept the asnwer. Glad to know that you have solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1673t-7ZEzpZenbeK_HjCYyo824th4YE8Vt9YAn1J0nU","Sheet1!A1:C1");IMPORTRANGE("1673t-7ZEzpZenbeK_HjCYyo824th4YE8Vt9YAn1J0nU","Sheet1!A2:C4");IMPORTRANGE("1J5VRivxfxToObBikLAKfNDNX4ibxvIWphcjohw0B8Ms","Sheet1!A2:C4");IMPORTRANGE("1DRSAyjDN7v6UNjFiBtMvrfzIewV8_iE-GjrGkNBPwIU","Sheet1!A2:C4")},"Select * where Col1 is not null ")
```

**Explanation**

[`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) the header then the other tables.

Since you want all column set the query to `" Select * where Col1 is not null "`

Answer (score 0):

try first separately and give authorization for each spreadsheet, the error comes from a lack of coupling between spreadsheets